# How does one have "dirs" list the entire DIRSTACK from a script?

Tags: bash, shell-script

My test script:

```
#!/bin/bash
dirs -p >> work_note.txt
```

In a stack of 10 directories I only get back the top 1
If I run `dirs -p` or `dirs -v` on the command line I get the entire stack.

Any tips or knowledge on what I am missing would be appreciated.

**NOTE**
My primary goal is to create a logout process that writes the DIRSTACK
to a file so I can recall what work I was doing in a terminal. I usually have 
multiple terminals going.

Answer (score 2):

The `DIRSTACK` is a local variable and is not passed into scripts, subshells, child processes, and so forth. I recommend using a function loaded into your `.bashrc` instead of a script.

Comment: The correct term is `shell variable`

Comment: I think I just realized that it's probably local to the shell. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I used this trick to retrieve my dir stack over every sessions.
I used to save it on a file.
I am also able to import / export to other terminals

Define this function in your .bashrc

```
stackd () 
{ 
    SAVEIFS=$IFS;
    IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b");
    builtin cd $@ && builtin pushd "$PWD" > /dev/null;
    dirs -l -p >> $HOME/.iostackd/dirstack && sort -u -o $HOME/.iostackd/dirstack $HOME/.iostackd/dirstack > /dev/null;
    IFS=$SAVEIFS
}
```

overload your buitin 'cd' by alias

```
alias cd='stackd "$1"'
```